# Django Allow Interaction with Users Data Only

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-authentication

I'm adding some user profile behavior to a Django app, and as usual I would like to restrict users from only being able to interact with their own data. This SO Q&A is related to the process itself:

[Django--- Allowing Users to only edit their profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44444011/django-allowing-users-to-only-edit-their-profile)

Is it enough to add the authenticated user id to the create, update, and delete queries? To reduce code duplication, I was thinking that I could write a mixin that would override `get_object` or `get_queryset` and intercept the query by adding the `self.request.user.pk` to filter the results?

Are there other efficient methods for doing this, or mixins from Django itself?

***edit*** This is what i was thinking:

```
    class OwnersDataOnlyViewMixin(object):
    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        if self.model == get_user_model():
            # user model, so pk of model should match self.request.user.pk
            return super().get_object(self.model.objects.filter(pk=self.request.user.pk))
        else:
            # different model
            try:
                # check for the 'user' field and filter on it if found
                user_field = self.model._meta.get_field('user')
                return super().get_object(self.model.objects.filter(user=self.request.user))
            except:
                # Mixin was used with model data not associated with a user
                raise self.model.DoesNotExist
```

There are probably more flexible ways of doing this, and I'm open to suggestions to improve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For class based views you will most likely need to override the [`get_querset()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_queryset) method as the queryset returned by it will be used for getting the data for editing and deleting, therefore return something like `MyModel.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)`. Note that this will result in a `404` - "Not Found" response if the user is trying to access an object that doesnt belong to him.

Upon creation of new objects you will mainly need to set `request.user` as the owner of the newly created object. This can be done with customizing the `CreateView`'s `form_valid()` method:

```
class MyCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.owner = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Depending on your model structure you can add this methods to a mixin and use them with the generic views.

Comment: I think what you described is just where I ended up just now, except I did `get_object` instead since `get_queryset` is not guaranteed to be called if `get_object` is overridden elsewhere. Then again, I suppose the same problem exists with my own override. For the create view, I did something similar to what you suggested as well using `form.instance`.

Comment: I've accepted your answer because that's pretty much where I ended up and seems like the right thing to do.